# How can I turn off a 3.3V circuit with a 3.3V microcontroller

Tags: switches, 3.3v, esp8266

I'm working with ATTiny85 that has low current (40 mA) GPIO. In the other side I have a power supply (battery with ~5V) connected to a LM317 and an ESP8266 that demands high current (more than the ATTiny85 can give, around 170 mA) and uses 3.3V.

I need to switch the ESP8266 (on/off). I tried some Darlington transistors, MOSFET and optocoupler but nothing works. All the examples that I see in the web is to switch from a 3.3V signal to a 5V (or more) circuit. In my case I want to switch from a 3.3V signal (ATTiny85 low current) to a 3.3V circuit (ESP8266 high current). Is this possible? And is so, how can I do this?

(I have a little background in electronic but I'm from computer science, so please try to be soft with your answers, thank you)

Comment: @R.Johnson How exactly do you expect that to work? He gets more power out than he puts in ... ?

Comment: @brhans He can simply use  MOSFET as a switch using the GPIO of the ATTiny85.  The regulator can be connected to the battery and ATTiny85 can turn it on/off. . .

Comment: Well yes, that will work much better than your original suggestion to use a 3.3V regulator.

Answer (score 8):

You should show us what circuit you've tried, but your simplest solution is this case would be a single P-channel MOSFET.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYKlVA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When your ATtiny's GPIO pin is high, the MOSFET will be switched off, and when the pin is low the MOSFET will be switched on. Make sure you connect the Drain & Source pins the right way! If you get it wrong the MOSFET's body diode will conduct and you won't be able to turn it off.

Note that this simple circuit will only work when you're switching the same supply voltage that your ATtiny runs from, and requires a MOSFET with a suitably low gate threshold voltage spec.

Comment: @brhans has a good answer. I would also suggest a gate to source resistor of around 10k to ensure MOSFET is off when micro is in reset. A good device would be NTR2101PT1G

Comment: you can remove the part number by double clicking on the part and deleting the text in the part number field, inside circuit lab.

Comment: Keep in mind that the P-MOSFET **must have a low treshold voltage (Vgs)**. Choosing a random transistor from your junk box will probably result in frustation, as the treshold voltage is usually -5V or worse making it impossible to turn on using a -3.3V potential. You need a treshold voltage better than -3V, such transistors are known as "logic level".

Answer (score 7):

Currently I don't have the ESP8266 module to test this, but I think that you can use `CH_PD` pin to turn it on and off.

No additional components required, just connect ATTiny85 and ESP8266 directly to your power source (3.3V from LM317) and one of the MCU GPIO pins to the ESP8266 `CH_PD` pin. When you set `CH_PD` pin high (3.3V), ESP8266 should turn on. And when you set `CH_PD` pin low (GND), it should turn off.

[Getting Started with ESP8266 - Basic wiring](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=getting-started-with-the-esp8266#basic_wiring)

Comment: The total shutdown current is just 500nA, so this should work very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Reed Relay.  Choose a relay with 5 volt coil. (or if you can find 3.3v coil).

Your 3.3v output pin can drive an NPN transistor to energise the reed relay coil.

The relay contacts can connect however you desire to power the ESP8266.

[Common Data Sheet](http://www.alliedelec.com/images/products/datasheets/bm/NTE_ELECTRONICS/70011933.pdf)  for reed relay

Answer (score -1):

So you seem to be confused about something (or I am, or both).

1. If you're asking about a way to buffer the current from the SPI on the AtTiny going into the ESP8266 SPI inputs. There are several ways of doing that. **But, fortunately for you, you don't need to do that.** The drive and sink capabilities of the ESP8266 is 12mA per data pin. Your AtTiny should get along swimmingly with the wifi dongle.
2. If you're talking about a way to control power to the ESP89266 board, then a P-Channel Mosfet connected the way brhans has it is the way to go.
3. If you insist you want a buffer between the AtTiny and the esp8266 then just use an inverter that is capable of sourcing and sinking the current you want.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo4nG8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Keep in mind that what you have shown is an inverting buffer. Also, as shown, it will short out the 3.3 V supply through the two B-E junctions unless you add some resistance in series with each of the bases.